# How can I change all cells of a specific column in a list?

Tags: c#, list, data-binding

I have a list "list". Saving itself works fine, for one cell in the Column "ColumnA" at each, which is selected with indexCounter.

It looks like this:

```
list[indexCounter].ColumnA = textBox.Text;
```

But I want something like this:

```
list[AllItems.Of].ColumnA = textBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to change field `ColumnA` of every `list` item? If yes, try this:

```
foreach(var item in list) {
    item.ColumnA = textBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Exactly like this, but I get an error sadly :/ String cannot implicit to int... I tried Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text) but still not working :(

Comment: Could you provide example of value witch you tried convert to int32?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Here's a screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/xFB2oBy

Comment: Why you call `list.Add()`? You want add new item with similar properties as `item`, but with new value of `ErloesKonto`? If you just want change value of `ErloesKonto` of item use similar syntax as at my answer. Now you trying add new element to list, but using wrong syntax. Change value of `ErloesKonto` firstly, then write `list.Add(item)`.

Comment: What? I don't quite understand. What Code I have to change exactly? Theres nothing like "item" when I write i...  Theres no  ------->item<-----.ColumnA = textBox.Text;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ForEach` method of `List` class.

```
list.ForEach(a => a.ColumnA = textBox.Text);
```

Comment: theres no method like "ForEach" on my list